# Why did the favorite button become little different and smaller?

Tags: support, design, bookmarks

So now currently the favorite button looks like:

[image]

But previously, it looks little bigger, and contains a border for the star, did stack exchange update it?

I think it looks better before, would we change it back? :-)

Also some other features has been updated.

So my questions are:

> Why did the favorite button became little different and smaller?

---

> Why did they update the features again, why do they need to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be more specific, the favorite button is now smaller due to the adoption of universal theming and the [Stacks design system](https://stackoverflow.design/).

The whole voting sidebar is now a flex-box column of buttons and the voting/ favorite icons were converted from a sprite to SVG.

For more information, see [Keyboard-only users cannot upvote/downvote posts or comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313769/keyboard-only-users-cannot-upvote-downvote-posts-or-comments/320635#320635).

Comment: Nice one too. good one :-) !!!

Comment: @U9-Forward No problem, I just happen to come across that announcement.

Comment: Lol, thanks tho :-) i created my MSE account.

Answer (score 0):

The favorite button became smaller because the theme was updated and it got changed.

The theme got changed because it hasn't been in a while, and it was starting to look kinda old, so it got updated.

Whether it looks better now or before is a matter of opinion. I definitely prefer it this way, though.

Comment: *The theme got changed because it hasn't been in a while* ... this would be the most weird reason to revise anything.