# Vote buttons, stars, and moderator margin controls just got a lot lighter

Tags: support, status-completed, design, accessibility

The controls in the left margin of a post -- vote buttons, star, and moderator controls (timeline, flag count, deleted comments) are now a much lighter shade of gray than they used to be.

Before (image taken from a [post on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/a/8162/21539)):

[image: screenshot]

After:

[image: screenshot]

Here is an example that shows the moderator tools (from Mi Yodeya, where the background color is light tan rather than white):

[image: screenshot with mod tools]

I find that lighter gray a *lot* harder to see, especially for the small numbers.  I'm not talking about the large score; that text is still readable.  The other text is already small, and light gray text on a white background is hard to see, as are the smaller controls.  I don't really care all that much if the vote buttons, which are larger, are lighter than they were, but as controls get smaller or include small text, the lighter gray becomes more of an obstacle.

Can you please darken this?  The previous value was much easier to see; I now struggle with the moderator tools.

Comment: Maybe they need to replace the ribbon in the printer?  But seriously, I find a lack of contrast in text hard to read, and this light gray doesn't have much contrast against the white.

Comment: Have you checked the contrast in those items? They may not meet accessibility standards: https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/contrast-minimum I'll admit idk if some of those items need to be high contrast.

Comment: Was this a recent change? Because I thought for sure they looked lighter, and harder to see, but then again I thought it could of been me.

Comment: @David yes, recent -- probably happened late Friday (or could be Saturday, but I doubt they push non-emergency changes on weekends).

Comment: Pretty sure this is related to/caused by : https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320635/284336 not sure why the shade of grey was changed or if we can get to fixing it over the break but I'll make sure they know about it.

Comment: I've darkened these up a bit. I bet we could go another step still, but builds aren't currently happening with the holiday break, so it'll take a while to actually see the fix. Sit tight!

Comment: Thanks @AaronShekey!  I was assuming I wouldn't get a response until after Jan 1, so I appreciate you giving me this update even though we have to wait for the build.