# Voting buttons are displayed on questions with historical lock and their answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, historical-lock

Previously, historically locked questions (and the answers) had their voting buttons hidden. The [faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) says:

> In addition to the post notice being prominently displayed, posts which are historically locked are "frozen in time": they cannot be voted on, flagged, answered, edited or commented (though they can be favorited, and ♦ moderators can edit and comment; moderator edits to historically locked posts do not bump the posts). **The visual appearance of the entire post is altered by removing the voting arrows from the question and all answers.**

Now, somehow the voting buttons are shown on historically locked posts:

- [The new top bar is out on meta. Consider it a beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta?rq=1)
- ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

[image: Historically locked post with voting buttons]

This is probably related to the [recent changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313769/keyboard-only-users-cannot-upvote-downvote-posts-or-comments/320635#320635), especially as the buttons are hidden in the mobile view ("mobile" link in the footer) as [Solomon Ucko](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/308329/solomon-ucko) noted in the comments.

Comment: The next step: allowing users the right to vote on these posts. New answers and/or comments cannot be posted but users, new and old, should be allowed to express their preferences. I don't see why not! :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA nope, my vote is unfortunately rejected. :D Maybe something like the election system for these poll questions?

Comment: Oh, I already know that votes cannot be cast, I was just suggesting that this should be the next step :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA yeah, I understood this but proposed to use the election system as an alternative...

Comment: FWIW, it hides the button on the mobile site (not the app).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The arrows will be hidden again starting with the next production build.

Long story short, the desktop views were refactored some to add better accessibility features to the voting arrows, and the bits that were there to hide the arrows were accidentally removed.