# Edit comment yields [object Object] instead of comment text

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, edits

At some point this afternoon the edit comment functionality was changed and now when you edit a comment you see `[object Object]` instead of the text. If I click edit here:

> [image]

I see this:

> [image]

This is happening on at least Database Administrators, Stack Overflow, and this site, so it is probably network-wide.

Comment: Go ahead, try it here. Add a comment, wait the requisite 5 seconds, then try to edit it.

Comment: [object Object]

Comment: Reproduced here; moderators please see edit history of comment above.

Comment: Ha. Same here on EL&U https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11620/has-there-been-any-css-changes-in-the-last-week#comment49466_11620

Comment: [object Object] That's bloody weird.

Comment: Well, it’s easy to explain what went wrong: when editing a comment a string is expected as the current comment text, but whatever function handles comment edits receives an object (which may include the actual text) instead. The object is inserted as the value, thus automatically stringified, and by default you get `[object Object]`. This is most likely due to some change of the editing logic.

Comment: Thread from [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372714/edit-comment-shows-object-object-instead-of-previous-comment-text)

Comment: [object Object] @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog that's actually pretty funny) A flashmob of [object Object] anyone?  (Damn, I just had to say it!)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is my fault, the fix is live now for MSE, building on the network.

In working on [Keyboard-only users cannot flag comments in the new comment flag dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313761/keyboard-only-users-cannot-flag-comments-in-the-new-comment-flag-dialog/314306#314306), I needed access to the event that showed the flagging dialog, so I updated the comment UI hooks to pass in the event as the first parameter.

This was fine fo the various hooks, upvote, flag, etc, except for edit, because the edit hook already had a parameter defined `textOverride`.  So the event that was passed in was treated as a text override and replaced the edit text.

Comment: On the bright side, at least you were not getting [object Object] when editing this post :)