# Space triggers confirm dialog regarding reversal of vote on comments

Tags: bug, comments, up-votes, user-experience, keyboard

I use <kbd>space</kbd> to scroll down on the page, but a recent change has left me unable to do this after upvoting a comment.

Previously it would just keep scrolling, but now it triggers an attempt of undoing my vote and I'm presented with the confirm dialog:

[image]

Previously it would just scroll again after having voted on a comment.

Is this an intended change?

Comment: [Possible related:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314306/287256) “The comment upvote and flag buttons are now <button>s, meaning they are tab-able”