# Using the Space key to upvote/un-upvote a comment does not work

Tags: bug, comments, accessibility, keyboard

Upvoting and un-upvoting a comment is not possible using the <kbd>Space</kbd> key. This used to work before: [Space triggers confirm dialog regarding reversal of vote on comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314337/space-triggers-confirm-dialog-regarding-reversal-of-vote-on-comments)

Here's a GIF showing how upvoting/un-upvoting a comment using the <kbd>Space</kbd> key currently works:

[image]

The GIF shows that <kbd>Tab</kbd>'ing puts focus on the upvote button, but pressing the <kbd>Space</kbd> key doesn't add an upvote to the comment, or in the case of un-upvoting, the confirmation dialog confirming to un-upvote is *not* shown. Instead, the page just scrolls down.

However, the <kbd>Space</kbd> key *does* work for the flag button:

[image]

Another bug to note is that there is no highlight on the flag button after <kbd>Tab</kbd>'ing to focus on it.